# How do I plot a single contour for a 3rd degree polynomial in 2 variables in python?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, polynomials

I have an equation for a surface. It is a polynomial in 2 variables to the 3rd degree. I wrote the following lambda function for it:

```
def get_poly(w):
    return lambda x1, x2 : w[0] + w[1]*x1 + w[2]*x1 + w[3]*x1**2 + w[4]*x1*x2 + w[5]*x2**2 + w[6]*x1**3 + w[7]*x1**2*x2 + w[8]*x1*x2**2 + w[9]*x2**3
```

where all `w[0]..w[9]` are known. I want to plot a single contour of this surface where `z = 0`. How do I do that? Thank you for your help.

Comment: It always helps to tell the actual problem. In this case why would `plt.contour(x1,y1,get_poly(w)(x1,y1), [0])` not work? Any error?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but how would you define x1 and y1 (I believe you meant x2) here?

Comment: Did you read the [contour demo](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/contour_demo.html)? If there is anything unclear about that, maybe better ask for that first?